# CodeIgniter delete function not hitting mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm making an ajax call to the controller:

```
$.ajax({
            url: base_url + "user/removeIngredientFromRecipe",
            type: "POST",
            data: { 'deleted_ingredients`': deleted_ingredients },
            success: function() {
                console.log("Deleted " + deleted_ingredients);
            },
            error: function(status, responseText) {
                console.log(status + ": " + responseText)
            }
        });
```

I'm posting "deleted_ingredients", it's an array of integers.

Controller code:

```
function removeIngredientFromRecipe()
{
    $data = $_POST;
    $this->db->where_in('recipe_ingridient_id',$data['deleted_ingredients'])->delete('recipe_ingridients');
    return TRUE;
}
```

I've verified that the array has the correct integers, the delete statement works from the mySQL console.

I can see that the URL is being called from the apache logs:
66.194.3.158 - - [16/Dec/2013:19:57:50 +0000] "POST /user/removeIngredientFromRecipe HTTP/1.1" 200 26

and it returns an HTTP 200.
In mySQL- I'm logging all queries, and I never see the delete statement hit the db.  This leaves me thinking that I'm making it to the controller, but have my delete function configured incorrectly, or possibly don't have something loaded.  Any thoughts on what I'm missing/did wrong?

FYI- the misspellings of 'ingredient' are intentional and correct, legacy code from previous developers. :(

Not the world's strongest PHP dude, so no suggestion unwelcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Un-needed backtick?  `'deleted_ingredients\`' <--`

Comment: There is a backtick in ajax data part is this a type **type: "POST",
            data: { 'deleted_ingredients`': deleted_ingredients },**

Comment: Looks like your PHP is mixing some `ingridient` with `ingredient`. That'll come back to haunt you.

Comment: FYI: No need to use $_POST in Codeigniter. It's provided for you via $this->input->post(), all nice and squeaky clean. Also, since you're using Codeigniter (MVC) you shouldn't be making DB calls in your controller, those should be in your models.

Comment: DOH!  It was the backtick....

Comment: You're right MonkeyZeus- I'll be fixing the different spellings as part of this release.